# How to lock rotation from a TableViewController child of NavigationController on TabBarController

Tags: ios, swift3, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, xcode8.2

I've been stuck on this for a while now and can't figure out how I can override the "shouldAutoRotate" variable of TabBarController from the child (Navigation Controller ---> TableViewController)

So basically here's my setup
TabBarController ---> Navigation Controller ---> Main TableViewController ---> VocabularyDetail TableviewController

I know the below overrides in TabBarController will lock the rotation for all child views.

```
override var supportedInterfaceOrientations : UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.portrait
}

override var shouldAutorotate : Bool {
    return false
}
```

However the challenge is that I want to selectively do this override depending on which view has been loaded into the navigation controller. If you look at the picture, the last controller is "*Vocabulary Detail*" which is the one that should change the "*shouldAutorotate*" variable to true.[image: TabBar to Navigation to tableView]

- iOS 10
- Xcode 8.2
- Swift 3

Comment: Anyone? any pointers would help....

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out :) 
For those out there who are stuck at the same problem, here's the solution.

You need to write two *extensions*. One for the TabBarController and one for the NavigationController. Then in the extension of the Navigation controller you will need to override the values you're interested in by checking the view that's being loaded into the navigation.

UITabBarController extension will basically pass on the value from the child UINavigationController

```
extension UITabBarController {

    override open var shouldAutorotate: Bool {
        get {
            if let visibleVC = selectedViewController {
                return visibleVC.shouldAutorotate
            }
            return super.shouldAutorotate
        }
    }

    override open var preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation: UIInterfaceOrientation{
        get {
            if let visibleVC = selectedViewController {
                return visibleVC.preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
            }
            return super.preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
        }
    }

    override open var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask{
        get {
            if let visibleVC = selectedViewController {
                return visibleVC.supportedInterfaceOrientations
            }
            return super.supportedInterfaceOrientations
        }
    }
}
```

UINavigation extension will check for the view being loaded and set the proper value for the overrides. Below will basically allow my screens to rotate, but to the orientation that I'm interested. All views other than Flashcard will stay in Portrait, while flashcard will only be in landscape.

```
extension UINavigationController {

    override open var shouldAutorotate: Bool {
        get {
            if let visibleVC = visibleViewController {
                return visibleVC.shouldAutorotate
            }
            return super.shouldAutorotate
        }
    }

    override open var preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation: UIInterfaceOrientation{
        get {
            if let visibleVC = visibleViewController {
                if visibleVC.isKind(of: FlashCardController.classForCoder()) {
                    return UIInterfaceOrientation.landscapeLeft
                } else {
                    return UIInterfaceOrientation.portrait
                }
            }
            return super.preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
        }
    }

    override open var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask{
        get {
            if let visibleVC = visibleViewController {
                if visibleVC.isKind(of: FlashCardController.classForCoder()) {
                    return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.landscape
                } else {
                    return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.portrait
                }
            }
            return super.supportedInterfaceOrientations
        }
    }
}
```